# AWS S3 copy folder without using listobject

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to copy a folder within the same bucket and then run various logic on the copied content.
I wanted to know if there's a way to copy the entire folder without using `listObjects` and then proceeding to copying each file separately.

Because this would mean running `listObjects` and copying each file and then doing `listObjects` again on the new folder and then running logic on each file.

So basically I'm trying to save IO and avoid multiple loops.

Please advise.

Comment: The only way to know the contents of your Bucket is to use `ListObjects` or [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. Each object would need to be copied individually.

Comment: please post your comment as an answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--recursive` tag in your SDK of choice to accomplish this. Combine this with the `--include` and `--exclude` flags which can use wild cards, you can achieve your goal. [See this page of the CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

something like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/logs/ s3://mybucket/logs2/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not provide a command that 'copies a folder'. Instead, **each object must be individually copied** via its own API request.

This means that you will first need to **obtain a listing of the objects**. This can be obtained via:

- A call to `ListObjects` (note: It can only return a maximum of 1000 objects per API call)

*OR*

- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to generate a list of existing objects in CSV format, and then use that list to generate the Copy requests

If you have a *large* number of objects, you could consider using **Amazon S3 Batch Operations**, which can copy files or invoke an AWS Lambda function for each object.

You could also configure Amazon S3 to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever an object is Created (including when it is copied). Thus, the creation of the object can directly trigger the logic that you want to run.